# Angular cannot pass route data by calling service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on Angular 8.2.5 and I am trying to pass route data by calling a service. I have a lazy loaded module that I want to import it in several other modules. I will pass a PermissionHandlerModule service which will contain each parent module permissions:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                canActivate: [AppRouteGuard],
                canActivateChild: [AppRouteGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'route1',
                        component: Component1,
                        //data: { permission: 'MyModulePermissionsForRoute1' },
                        data: { permission: IPermissionHandler.route1Permission },
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'route2',
                        component: Component12,
                        data: { permission: IPermissionHandler.route1Permission },
                    },
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})

@Injectable()
export abstract class IPermissionHandler {
    abstract route1Permission: string;
    abstract route2Permission: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class PermissionHandlerModuleA implements IPermissionHandler {
    route1Permission: string = 'ModuleARoute1Permission';
    route2Permission: string = 'ModuleARoute2Permission';
}

@Injectable()
export class PermissionHandlerModuleB implements IPermissionHandler {
    route1Permission: string = 'ModuleBRoute1Permission';
    route2Permission: string = 'ModuleBRoute2Permission';
}

// Module A imports section
{ provide: PermissionHandlerModuleA, useClass: IPermissionHandler}

// Module B imports section
{ provide: PermissionHandlerModuleB, useClass: IPermissionHandler}
```

How can I achieve something like the above?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an injection token for something like this.

```
export interface IPermissionHandler {
    handle: () => void;
}
```

And then the token:

```
export const PERMISSION_HANDLER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<IPermissionHandler>('PERMISSION_HANDLER');
```

Now say you have two services implementing `IPermissionHandler` namely `PermissionHandler1` and `PermissionHandler2` which are in two different modules. Say for the first module, you want to use `PermissionHandler1` then you need to provide in this way:

```
provide: PERMISSION_HANDLER_TOKEN, useClass: PermissionHandler1
```

In another module you can use:

```
provide: PERMISSION_HANDLER_TOKEN, useClass: PermissionHandler2
```

Then, wherever you want to use the service, you can inject in this way:

```
constructor(@Inject(PERMISSION_HANDLER_TOKEN) private handler: IPermissionHandler) {}
```

Comment: and how am I going to pass it in the routes declaration in the data section?

Comment: and add the permissions there?